# get the "last occurrence" of the year

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I am converting my scheduling spreadsheet to mysql as it has become too large to continue using.

I am trying to create a view that shows the last occurrence date of a job being complete. I also don't want to count previous years as they would be considered a new "cycle" so to speak. The "last_occurance" table(view) shows what I would like the result to be.

I'm no expert at sql, but essentially I would want something like:

> SELECT client_id FROM clients *and based on those results get the last
> occurance of each jobs within the year '2023'*

I tried the following, but it returns too many results (all jobs):

> SELECT clients.name, jobs.date_completed FROM clients NATURAL JOIN
> jobs;

[image]